# Comma delimited numeric value fails validation in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this model class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class PropertyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String BuildingStyle { get; set; }
        public int BuiltYear { get; set; }
        [Range(1, 100000000, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 1 and 100,000,000.")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0,0}")]
        [Display(Name = "Price")]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string AgentName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication1.Models;`

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class PropertyController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            PropertyModel model = new PropertyModel
            {
                AgentName = "John Doe",
                BuildingStyle = "Colonial",
                BuiltYear = 1978,
                Price = 650000,
                Id = 1
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(PropertyModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Save property info.              
            }

            return View(model);
        }         
    }
}
```

And this view:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.PropertyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <text>Built Year: </text>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BuiltYear)<br />
    <text>Building Style: </text>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BuildingStyle)<br />
    <text>Agent Name: </text>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AgentName)<br />
    <text>Price: </text>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price)<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

[image]

If I enter the price without any commas, ModelState.IsValid is true. But if I enter the price as a comma delimited value, ModelState.IsValid is false (see the screenshot). What do I need to do in order to be able to enter numeric values with commas and pass the model validation?  I know implementing my own custom model binder is an option, but I want to make that the last option.  Thank you. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
public int Price { get; set; }
```

The reason is your Price is set into `int`. It would definetley cause an error if you place a comma. If you want a comma, just change your `int` into a `string` then if your going to use it for computations, just use the `split[',']` to split the comma and convert it to `int` by using the `Convert.ToInt32()` method.

Comment: Thanks, but if I change the data type to string, I won't be able to use some annotations out of the box for int, such as [Range(1, 100000000)], correct?

Answer (score 2):

Which version of MVC you are using ?

As you are displaying comma for price text, I suggest you should use custom ModelBinder to get its values.

Comment: The title of this question says it is MVC4. Yes, I can do a custom ModelBinder as I mentioned, but I'd like to make that the last option.

Comment: So I decided to implement my own custom model binder. But I am running into issues. I have a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145780/asp-net-mvc-4-how-to-validate-my-model-in-a-custom-model-binder . Could you take a look?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change the data type of your Price to a string so that it would pass the validation.  By doing that though, you would have to do some additional checking to see that the string passed in is truly a valid int.  A little extra work, but not too bad.

Comment: Thanks. I am a little reluctant to change the data type to string. It should be a numeric data type.

Comment: I understand.  But if you truly want the comma, you will either have to use it as a string and convert it to an int manually or use a custom ModelBinder.  I'm not sure how else you can do it.

Comment: The customer insisting in having the comma feature, so I have no choice. I wonder if I can do this: Define public string PriceAsString for the input, and also define public int Price, which internally converts PriceAsString to an int. So, the view would have @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.PriceAsString).  However, this probably also means that I won't be able to annotate PriceAsString using [Range(1, 100000000)] out of the box, and have to do some custom validation.

Comment: Yes, that will accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Success Code Here**
http://blog.rebuildall.net/2011/03/02/jQuery_validate_and_the_comma_decimal_separator

in Model->  [Range(1, 100000000, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 1 and 100,000,000.")]

in View (javascript) ->

```
 $.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
    var globalizedValue = value.replaceAll(",", "");
    return this.optional(element) || (globalizedValue >= param[0] && 
    globalizedValue <= param[1]);
 }
```